Retrofit data sending
It's my first time trying to fetch data from the server in Kotlin using Retrofit so I'm sorry if the question sounds dumb to you.
API interface
@POST("/api/finger-print")
    suspend fun createFingerPrint(
        @Query("databaseName") name: String,
        @Body type: FingerPrint,
        @Header("Authorization") token:String,
    ): CheckResponse

API function
suspend fun check(dbName:String, token:String, checkType:String): CheckResponse {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                // Call the Retrofit API method
                val type = FingerPrint(checkType)
                val response = apiService.createFingerPrint(dbName, type, token)
                println(response)
                // Process response here if needed
                response
            } catch (e: HttpException) {
                // Handle HTTP errors
                throw IOException("error 53: $e")
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                // Handle IO errors
                throw IOException("error 56: ${e.message}")
            }
        }
    }

Activity
private suspend fun checkInOut(type: String, callback: (String) -> Unit) {
    try {
      val response = api.check(dbName, token, type)
      println(response)
      val status = response.status

      // Check if the API returned "true" status
      if (status == "true") {
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
          // Success
          callback.invoke("Success")
        }
      } else {
        // Failed
        callback.invoke("CA Error 523")
      }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
      // Catch any unknown errors
      e.printStackTrace()
      callback.invoke("CA Error 532")
    }
  }

Data classes
data class FingerPrint (
    val type:String
)

data class CheckResponse(
  val status:String,
  val data: CheckData
)

data class CheckData(
  val name:String,
  val userID:String,
  val email:String,
  val time:String,
  val date:String,
  val type:String,
  val _id:String,
)

But I keep getting this error:
java.io.IOException: error 53: retrofit2.HttpException: HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
The server expects this (This is what I do on Postman)
URL: {{URL}}finger-print?databaseName=myDB
Body-raw: {"type":"Check-in"}
Authorization: Bearer Token
All data are being sent correctly but I think the problem is with how I'm setting the authorization header
I've checked a couple of online questions like this but I couldn't figure out how to set the token
Also, before that error, I was getting this one
java.io.IOException: error 53: retrofit2.HttpException: HTTP 400 Bad Request
But after I extracted the body part to a data class (was like this @Body type:String) I got the code 500 error

You can apply header using interceptor.
class HeaderInterceptor() : Interceptor {
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        
        
        val builder = Headers.Builder()
        builder.add("Authorization", yourToken)

        val request = chain.request().newBuilder()
            .headers(builder.build())
            .build()
        return chain.proceed(request)
    }
}

Then, build your retrofit client as below.
object RetrofitBuilder {
    fun build(): ApiService {
        val headerInterceptor = HeaderInterceptor()
        val clientBuilder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(headerInterceptor)
        val client = clientBuilder.build()

        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(converterFactory)
            .client(client)
            .build()
        return retrofit.create(ApiService::class.java)
    }
}

Create the service (your API Interface)
val apiService = RetrofitBuilder.build()


Reference https://square.github.io/okhttp/features/interceptors/

Thanks mate, it worked!
I never found anyone talking about interceptors and it's my first time seeing it, thanks for your clear answer (I had to do some modifications though)
